# How Do I Rig A Car With Camber

Tags: animation, drivers

I need to animate a car so that the wheels spin when it moves. I tried using drivers but it doesn't rotate the wheels locally, and the camber causes them to wobble.

Is there a better way to animate the car so that the wheels don't wobble?

[image]

[image]

Comment: keep them vertical, parent them to empties (or bones), tilt the empties. To make them rotate you can use a Transformation constraint with the car as Target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the wheel vertical, parent it to an empty, tilt the empty, parent the empty to the car (also doable with bone):

[image]

To make the wheel rotate when the car moves forwards, give it a *Transformation* constraint with the car as *Target*, enable *Extrapolate*, *Map From > Location*, choose the location amplitude (here *Y Min* and *Max >* -1 and +1), under *Map To > Rotation* choose the rotation axis and what is the target location axis that will be taken into account (here *X Source Axis > Y* and *Min > -90°, Max > 90°*):

[image]

Duplicate the empty and the wheel, move the car:

[image]

Comment: Did you just abuse Suzanne as a wheel replacement?! xD

Comment: yes I thought a sado-masochistic car would be good  ^^  not sure it will be nice to drive though